# Hyper terminal git bash configuration for windows 10

Tags: git-bash, hyperterminal

When I try to add Hyper(Hyper Terminal) configurations for git bash to text(in that file it says "The system cannot find the path specified.") file it asks where to save, What location should I give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about when launching hyper you get that error.  you will find the you need to indicate the path to where git is located which will most likely be in programs folder, you will need to edit your .hyper.js file located in AppData\Roaming\hyper\  folder.  Here is a good document for editing that file: https://gist.github.com/jhnferraris/09700aa0a7dfb4dfaed30016500a7d11

When you install hyper in windows it automatically adds it to installed app launcher so you should be good there.

Answer (score 0):

To configure your Hyper Terminal, you need to add some settings in the .hyper.js file which can be easily accessed by opening a new hyper terminal (right click anywhere and open hyper terminal).

Click on the top-left of the terminal, `Edit -> Preferences`, opens the .hyper.js file. [Configure](https://hyper.is/#cfg) as per your needs and save the file to see the changes in effect.